# Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: jpa, oracle-11g, jdbc

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto web con springframework y api jpa. Al tratar de conectar con BBDD Oracle, me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Estado HTTP 500 – Internal Server Error
Tipo Informe de Excepción

mensaje Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAttributes org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement, java.lang.String)'

Descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

excepción
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAttributes org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement, java.lang.String)'
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1053)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


causa raíz
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAttributes org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement, java.lang.String)'
    org.springframework.transaction.annotation.SpringTransactionAnnotationParser.parseTransactionAnnotation(SpringTransactionAnnotationParser.java:42)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.determineTransactionAttribute(TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:229)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.findTransactionAttribute(TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:208)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.computeTransactionAttribute(TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:412)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.getTransactionAttribute(TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:345)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:119)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.findByOrderByDescripcion(Unknown Source)
    cl.awakelab.simulacro1td.servicio.EspecialidadesServicioImpl.listaEspecialidades(EspecialidadesServicioImpl.java:22)
    cl.awakelab.simulacro1td.controlador.FinalControlador.verportal(FinalControlador.java:28)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

A continuacion detallo, lo que aparece en la consola(esta abreviado) :

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions (file:/C:/Users/Administrador/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Simulacro1TD/WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext initialized in 13060 ms
oct. 14, 2021 11:56:48 A. M. org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'appServlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'appServlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 4603 ms
oct. 14, 2021 11:56:53 A. M. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
oct. 14, 2021 11:56:53 A. M. org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [31694] milliseconds
oct. 14, 2021 11:56:55 A. M. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [appServlet] en el contexto con ruta [/simulacro1td] lanzó la excepción [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAttributes org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement, java.lang.String)'] con causa raíz
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAttributes org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement, java.lang.String)'
    at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.SpringTransactionAnnotationParser.parseTransactionAnnotation(SpringTransactionAnnotationParser.java:42)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.determineTransactionAttribute(TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:229)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.findTransactionAttribute(TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.computeTransactionAttribute(TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.getTransactionAttribute(TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:345)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.findByOrderByDescripcion(Unknown Source)
    at cl.awakelab.simulacro1td.servicio.EspecialidadesServicioImpl.listaEspecialidades(EspecialidadesServicioImpl.java:22)
    at cl.awakelab.simulacro1td.controlador.FinalControlador.verportal(FinalControlador.java:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

El Pom configurado :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>cl.awakelab</groupId>
    <artifactId>simulacro1td</artifactId>
    <name>Simulacro1TD</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>5.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        <org.hibernate-em-version>4.3.8.Final</org.hibernate-em-version>
        <org.springframework.data-version>1.9.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.data-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
                
        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   
        
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
                
        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <!-- Dependencia para jdbc-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependencias incorporadas para jpa-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.data-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate-em-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            </dependency>
        <!-- Dependencias para Rest -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>              
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

el root-context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"   
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">
    
    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    
    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring/jdbc.properties" />
    
    <bean id="dataSource" 
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
        p:url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"
        p:username="XXXXXX" p:password="XXXXXXXX"/>

    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />

    <!-- Configure the entity manager factory bean -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        <!-- Set JPA properties -->
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="cl.awakelab.simulacro1td" />
    </bean>

    
    <!-- Configure the transaction manager bean -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="cl.awakelab.simulacro1td" />        
</beans>
```

el servlet-context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
    
    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
    
    <context:component-scan base-package="cl.awakelab.simulacro1td" />
    
    
    
</beans:beans>
```

jdbc.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost1521:xe
jdbc.username=XXXXXX
jdbc.password=XXXXXXXXX
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect
```

Ahora indicaré el paquete controlador. Hay 3 paquetes más que he creado, uno es para consultas sql,  otro para JunitTest, y un tercer paquete para aplicacion Java sin conexion a servidor.  Estos 3 últimos paquetes he decidido no agregarlos porque no generan errores al parecer.Por razones de caracteres, no he podido mostrar paquete modelo y servicio.

```
CONTROLADOR 

package cl.awakelab.simulacro1td.controlador;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import cl.awakelab.simulacro1td.modelo.Especialidades;
import cl.awakelab.simulacro1td.modelo.Reporte;
import cl.awakelab.simulacro1td.servicio.EspecialidadesServicio;
import cl.awakelab.simulacro1td.servicio.ReporteServicio;

@Controller
public class FinalControlador {

    @Autowired
    EspecialidadesServicio es;

    @Autowired
    ReporteServicio rs;

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String verportal(Model model) {
        List<Especialidades>listaespecialidades = es.listaEspecialidades();
        List<Reporte> listareporte = rs.obtenerReporte();
        model.addAttribute("lespecialidades", listaespecialidades);
        model.addAttribute("lreporte", listareporte);
        return "sitioinicio";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/verlistado",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String verReporte(Model model, 
            @RequestParam ("slcespecialidad") int idespecialidad ) {
        List<Especialidades> listaespecialidades = es.listaEspecialidades();
        List<Reporte> listareporte = rs.obtenerReportePorEspecialidad(idespecialidad);
        model.addAttribute("lespecialidades", listaespecialidades);
        model.addAttribute("lreporte", listareporte);
        return "sitioinicio";
    }
    
package cl.awakelab.simulacro1td.controlador;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import cl.awakelab.simulacro1td.modelo.Reporte;
import cl.awakelab.simulacro1td.servicio.ReporteServicio;

@RestController
public class RestControlador {

    @Autowired
    ReporteServicio rs;
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/obtenerregistros/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public List<Reporte> buscarDatos(@PathVariable("id") int idespecialidad){
        List<Reporte> listareporte = rs.obtenerReportePorEspecialidad(idespecialidad);
        return listareporte;
    } 
        
}
```

No se si será necesario agregar algo más. He intentado de ser lo más detallado, y he probado varias cosas como eliminar el servidor (Tomcat v 9.0) varias veces, o no sé si me faltara algún archivo de configuracion. En cuanto a la conexion con la base de datos Oracle , he puesto "Nombre de usuario de la Conexion a Base de datos" y la contraseña que pide esta. Indico esto, porque antes colocaba el "nombre de la conexion"(el que aparece arriba en Oracle").La verdad es que tratado varias alternativas, y agradecería sus respuestas como posibles soluciones.

Comment: Hola Juanpita40, esta publicación ha sido marcada como "demasiado extensa" automáticamente por el sistema. Las publicaciones que son muy extensas no suelen ser específicas y no reciben mucha atención por los usuarios. Trata de reducir el contenido y centrarte en el problema para que sea más fácil ayudarte (p.e. no incluyas todo tu código, sólo la función que falla, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

Hola no se si sea tu caso, pero justo tuve un error similar (Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ...) y buscando la respuesta, se me ocurrió mirar en el DAO y el ManagerImpl, y el error era que no estaba agregando la nueva función que había creado en el DAO en mi EntityDAO.